# How can I route to my S3 instance without showing my s3 link and instead keeping on the flask url route?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask

I want my s3 bucket url to be hidden and instead just show the original @app.route from my flask server. So far I have to do a redirect to the s3 bucket but I don't want my users to see the ugly s3 url and instead I want the neat url (example.com/s3bucketsite). How can I accomplish this within my flask server?

The reason I am doing it this way is because I have a url already purchased and used by this server side. I also have a front end I'd just like to have access to through this server route. What I've used: Url_for() doesn't work for s3 bucket url creating and Flask-s3 doesn't seem to be for this either.

```
@app.route('/mys3bucketfront')
def getS3site():
   return redirect('http://bucketname.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com')
```

From the redirect, I get what is expected: a redirect to the s3 url and that url showing in the address bar. I'd like to maintain the original app route by having a way to embed the s3 bucket endpoint in the app or masking the s3 bucket end point without a new CDN or url.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup your bucket for static website hosting.  It will give you a URL and then you can use DNS to create a an alias for that URL.

Reference: [Setting up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

Typically, people also use [Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).  It is a CDN that will improve the performance of your site, allows you to pass through requests to S3 and can allow you to associate a domain with SSL traffic to it so it is more secure.

References:

- [How to host your static website with S3 & CloudFront and set-up an SSL certificate?](https://medium.com/faun/how-to-host-your-static-website-with-s3-cloudfront-and-set-up-an-ssl-certificate-9ee48cd701f9)
- [How do I use CloudFront to serve a static website hosted on Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/)